# Kafka listener in test container, avoiding port 9092

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, testcontainers

I've written an Integration Test to show that a message sent to Kafka will arrive with a listener.  It passes if and only if I use `KAFKA_PORT=9092`.  That constant is the port used on the developer machine (or CI machine).

Ultimately I want to do this on a dynamically allocated port (i.e. using a `GenericContainer` and not a `FixedHostPortGenericContainer`) but for the moment I would simply like to be able to use a different port.

If I set KAFKA_PORT=59092 in the below code then the test fails and I see console output such as `Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established` e.g.:

```
2020-06-08 12:16:22.374  WARN 1371 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

I assume there is some additional configuration I need to do so that no
attempt is made to use port 9092, but this is eluding me.

A recreated, stripped back test is below, as is the associated `gradle.build`.

KafaSpikeFixedPort.java

```java
package com.example.kafkaspike;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Timeout;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.MessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource;
import org.testcontainers.containers.FixedHostPortGenericContainer;
import org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer;
import org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.Wait;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertAll;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
@Testcontainers
public class KafaSpikeFixedPort {

    // Test works only if this port is 9092 (matching the Docker container port)
    final static int KAFKA_PORT = 9092;

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void kafkaProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers",
                     () -> "kubernetes.docker.internal:"+ KAFKA_PORT);
        registry.add("spring.kafka.consumer.group-id",
                     () -> "test-consumer-group");
    }

    @Container
    private GenericContainer kafkaContainer =
            new FixedHostPortGenericContainer("obsidiandynamics/kafka:2.3.0-11")
                    .withFixedExposedPort(KAFKA_PORT, 9092)
                    .withExtraHost("kubernetes.docker.internal", "127.0.0.1")
                    .withEnv("KAFKA_LISTENERS",
                             "INTERNAL://:29092," +
                             "EXTERNAL://:"+KAFKA_PORT)
                    .withEnv("KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS",
                             "INTERNAL://kubernetes.docker.internal:29092," +
                             "EXTERNAL://kubernetes.docker.internal:"+KAFKA_PORT)
                    .withEnv("KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP",
                             "INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT," +
                             "EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT")
                    .withEnv("KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME",
                             "INTERNAL")
                    .waitingFor(Wait.forLogMessage(
                            ".*INFO\\s+\\[KafkaServer\\s+id=\\d+\\]" +
                            "\\s+started\\s+\\(kafka.server.KafkaServer\\).*",
                            1));

    @Autowired
    KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Autowired
    KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;

    private List<String> payloadsReceived = new ArrayList<>();

    @KafkaListener(autoStartup = "false", topics = "topic1")
    public void onMessage(@Payload String payload) {
        payloadsReceived.add(payload);
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEach() {
        payloadsReceived.clear();
        for(MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer : kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainers()) {
            listenerContainer.start();
        }
        sleep(2_000); // Just for the spike. (Eliminates code checking the listener container states.)
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void afterEach() {
        for(MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer : kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainers()) {
            listenerContainer.stop();
        }
        sleep(2_000); // Just for the spike. (Eliminates code checking the listener container states.)
    }

    @Test
    @Timeout(value = 3, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    public void test() {
        kafkaTemplate.send("topic1", "Hello World!");
        sleep(1_000); // Just for the spike. (Wait for message in production test, with test timeout.)
        assertAll(
                () -> assertEquals(1, payloadsReceived.size()),
                () -> assertEquals("Hello World!", payloadsReceived.get(0))
                 );
    }

    private void sleep(long millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

gradle.build

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.7.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test'
    // for TestContainers
    testCompile group: 'org.testcontainers', name: 'testcontainers', version: "1.14.1"
    testCompile group: 'org.testcontainers', name: 'junit-jupiter', version: "1.14.1"
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: So it turns out there are two problems with the above code.  Firstly the property "spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers" needs to be set (identically to "spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers"). Secondly, the KAFKA_LISTENERS environment variable should specify port 9092 and not the KAFKA_PORT. The test then passes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are reasons why [Testcontainers' Kafka module](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/) exists :)

It takes care of the ports setup by deferring running Kafka's process, so that it can provide the actual assigned random port as `ADVERTISED_HOST` env variable.

Try it, or have a look at the sources for some inspiration:
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/tree/master/modules/kafka

Comment: Thank you. This has been hugely useful. 

I'm going to mark this as the correct answer, because it has provided what now seems to be the correct way to proceed.

Comment: I was avoiding the Testcontainers' Kafka module because I thought it prescribed the docker image to use.  However the link to the source code (and specifically drilling down in to https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/master/modules/kafka/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers/KafkaContainer.java) explains things.

Comment: Not only does the overridden containerIsStarting() method reveal how they defer setting the internal port to match the dynamically allocated external port, but looking at the constructor reveals that the KafkaContainer using the kafka.container.image property (meaning that in production I can use KafkaContainer and my own image).